# How can I determine the form of my legend with BaseR?

Tags: r, plot, graph, legend

I'm trying to replicate the following chart:

[image]

This is what I managed to do so far:

```
library(carData)
UN <- as.data.frame(UN)

layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))

col.vec <- c("blue", "turquoise1", "green", "palegreen",
             "orange", "red", "violet", "purple")[UN$region]
pch.vec <- c(8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)[UN$region]


plot(UN$ppgdp, UN$infantMortality,
     xlab = "Gross Domestic Product per Capita",
     ylab = "Infant Mortality",
     xaxt = "n",
     las = 1,
     col = col.vec,
     pch = pch.vec)
axis(side = 1, at = c(0, 20000, 40000, 60000, 80000, 100000),
     labels = c(0, "", 40000, "", 80000, ""))

plot(UN$region, UN$infantMortality,
     xlab = "Region",
     ylab = "Infant Mortality",
     xaxt = "n",
     las = 1,
     col = c("blue", "turquoise1", "green", "palegreen",
             "orange", "red", "violet", "purple"))

plot.new()
legend('center', 
       legend = UN$region, 
       pch = pch.vec, 
       col = col.vec)
```

My problem is that I don't know how to determine the shape of the legend. I want exactly the same shape as in the picture above, a rectangle. Can somebody tell me how to do this (not using ggplot2 or any other package)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the factors to define `col` and `pch`. For the legend use just one `vec` with the levels and do `seq`uences along it. And use `tex.col=`.

```
library(carData)
UN <- as.data.frame(UN)

layout(matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 3), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))


plot(UN$ppgdp, UN$infantMortality,
     xlab = "Gross Domestic Product per Capita",
     ylab = "Infant Mortality",
     xaxt = "n",
     las = 1,
     col = UN$region,
     pch = as.numeric(UN$region))
axis(side = 1, at = c(0, 20000, 40000, 60000, 80000, 100000),
     labels = c(0, "", 40000, "", 80000, ""))

plot(UN$region, UN$infantMortality,
     xlab = "Region",
     ylab = "Infant Mortality",
     xaxt = "n",
     las = 1,
     col = c("blue", "turquoise1", "green", "palegreen",
             "orange", "red", "violet", "purple"))

plot.new()
vec <- levels(UN$region)

legend('center', 
       legend = vec, 
       ncol=4,
       pch = seq(vec), 
       col = seq(vec),
       text.col=seq(vec))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now, I am just a little confused because my symbols and colors are not the same as in the chart that I want to replicate... But I guess I messed something up inside my code.